# Rust lifetime of string slices within a vector within a struct

Tags: string, memory, vector, rust

While writing a program of mine, I came across a structure containing a vector of strings. My (basic) knowledge of Rust led me to wonder whether a `Vec<&str>` within a structure like this:

```rust
struct StrSliceVector<'a> {
    v: Vec<&'a str>
}
```

(that has the lifetime strongly related to the structure) is more efficient or allocates less heap-memory than this one:

```rust
struct StringVector {
    v: Vec<String>
}
```

I imagine that since in `StringVector` the `String`s are allocated in the heap, then it would result in a vector (also in the heap) containing pointers to other memory locations with the actual strings.
Does `StrSliceVector` allocate the strings internally to the vector heap-space?

Comment: P.S. All of my strings should be unmodifiable, so it's fine that `&str` results in an immutable value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `&str` takes up two `usize`s of memory (not including the string data its referencing) while a `String` takes up three `usize`s. But if this matters to you, then you can replace `String` with `Box<str>` to get the same size as a `&str` just as an owned version. Then you're back at simply looking at the logical difference of "owned" vs "borrowed".

A `&str` only references existing data, while the `String` owns its data. The only reason that the `String` version would take significantly more memory than `&str` would be if the strings are already owned elsewhere: in another structure or from a string literal, for example. If they are, then you're just copying what already exists, therefore using more memory. If you want a datatype that can handle both owned and borrowed data to save on allocations, consider using a [`Cow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html).

> Does `StrSliceVector` allocate the strings internally to the vector heap-space?

Both are `&str` and `String` are similar that *in-place* they are basically just pointers; the data will always exist elsewhere and not in-line with the `Vec` elements.

So in broad terms, `&str` will be more space-efficient, but lifetimes introduce more constraints that may make `StrSliceVector<'a>` unviable depending on how you intend to use it. Since references don't own their data, you must ensure that whatver does own the strings keeps them alive as long as you are using the vector.

Comment: It's important to note that converting `String` to `Box<str>` can allocate+copy.

Answer (score 3):

When you create the `Vec<String>`, you must decide whether you wish to *move* existing `String`s into the vector, or `clone` them in. If you move them in then no additional heap allocations are required, so it's the same total heap allocations as `Vec<&'a str>` from this point of view. Which is more appropriate depends on your use case. What do you wish to do with the elements of the vector?

If you don't require ownership of the strings in the vector for the operations you intend to perform, the string slice version should be your first instinct as it means the strings are still available for manipulation elsewhere in the code, after the vector has been dropped.